# flutter firebase firestore Remove duplicate values

Tags: flutter

I want to know how to remove duplicate values ​​in firestore

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicates before updating it to firestore

```
final Map<String, Movie> moviesMap = new Map();
moviesWithDuplicates.forEach((movie) {
  moviesMap[movie.id] = movie;
});
moviesWithoutDuplicates = moviesMap.values.toList();

// send moviesWithoutDuplicates to firestore
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of a duplicate check when submitting data to Firestore? I can't find any examples of it